# submit moving files in Perforce

Tags: perforce

I want to move files from one directory to another. I opened them and moved. now I want to submit the moving, but I have more files opened in perforce, that I **don't** want to submit.
How can I submit only two directories, and not all the opened files?
(I'm using the shell and not the gui)

I tried to submit one directory and after the other, but it was unsuccessful because it's moving files and needs the source and the destination in the same change list.

Answer (score 2):

Run `p4 change` and edit the `Files` field of the changelist form to list only the files that you want to include in the new changelist.  Now your files are split between two changelists and submitting one will not affect the other.